# NetworkX Multigraph from letter correspondence

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, networkx

Sorry, I'm not programming much for a long time, so my question may be rather verbose. I'm trying to develop a directed multigraph in networkX. My data is table with 25 letters between 2 people, send on different dates, received on different dates, etc, but only between these 2 people. Each row of the table (imported as a Pandas dataframe looks like this:

```
0   25-04-1838  George Sand Fryderyk Chopin GS-FC   On vous adore. George. et moi aussi!... 25-04-1838  27-04-1838  Paryż   Paris
```

With this code I can create the multigraph,

```
G1 = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, "letter_sent", "letter_recd", edge_attr=["letter_sent_recd"], create_using=nx.MultiGraph)
```

but I cannot figure out from the documentation and examples how to add figure out how to add attributes to the edges)

`G1.edges` returns this: `MultiEdgeView([('25-04-1838', '27-04-1838', 0), ...])`

Any suggestions how create the multigraph with edges?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please read [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). "please help me" is [not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question); we don't write code to specification. [You are expected to study the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) ahead of time; think of logical steps to solve the problem; figure out exactly where you are stuck, and be able to show exact input and output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right way to create your graph from a DataFrame:

```
G1 = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, "letter_sent", "letter_recd", 
                             edge_attr=["letter_sent_recd"], 
                             create_using=nx.MultiGraph)
```

To access to attribute, pass `data=True` as parameter of `G1.edges()`.

Example:

```
>>> G.edges
EdgeView([(0, 1), (1, 2)])

>>> G.edges()
EdgeView([(0, 1), (1, 2)])

>>> G.edges(data=True)  # what you are looking for
EdgeDataView([(0, 1, {'attr1': 20}), (1, 2, {'attr1': 10})])
```

Documentation:

- [`G1.edges`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.edges.html)
- [`nx.get_edge_attributes`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.get_edge_attributes.html#get-edge-attributes)

Comment: Thank you. It is helpful(I cannot upvote your comment). I have to go back to the first principles and better understand the data structure for multigraphs.